# BigQuery Access Token not Created with Proxy Server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Sometime after August 10th, 2018, I'm no longer able to obtain an oAuth20 Access Token when a Proxy Server is configured.
The oAuth Authorization call seems to be fine.

I receive HTTP 400 Bad Request when making the oAuth Token call.

This has worked for the past year until this problem just started occurring.

Without the Proxy Server configured, everything works fine.

Any idea what change was recently implemented in oAuth by Google to cause this issue.

It also happens with Google Analytics but that's expected as both BigQuery and Google Analytics use the same oAuth20 Authorization and Token URLs.

Someone let me know.

Efrem

Comment: you should create an issue for proper tracking: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654?s=issue_id:desc&p=1

Comment: As @Pentium10 said, it's better to ask for support in this case. If you have a Support package I will recommend you to create a case there, if not, use the link he provided.

Comment: Inigo, I created an issue with Google a couple of days ago. As the issue was assigned to a Security person, I didn't get a sense that the person understood that this is a general problem that was just introduced by Google.
The problem is specific to the Google oAuth Token call.
We don't have a Support package with Google.
Is there a way to escalate this issue with Google?

Comment: After investigation with our Development team, it seems that the cause of the Google oAuth Token call was failing because our application was sending an Absolute Path URL when using a Proxy Server.
We did a test with a Relative Path URL and we were successful in obtaining the Access Token.
But, from what I understand, the standard is that Absolute Path URLs should be sent when a Proxy Server is configured.

Comment: I've read the [Public issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112602622)  you created, and as the last comment says, I don't think further actions should be done by Google. As you solved your issue correcting the path when using your proxy, could you add it as an answer so other people can see it if the have the same question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: To add to my post from Aug 19 at 23:29, Google informed me that Relative Path has to be used even with a Proxy Server configured.
According to Section 5.1.2 of the W3C Specification, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html, The absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when the request is being made to a proxy.
We were following this specification.
But, it seems that Google doesn't follow this specification.
So, once we changed our Token request to use Relative Path, it started working.

Comment: Have you also tried investigating the exact requests coming out of the proxy as suggested by the Google engineer to ensure they are indeed correct?

Comment: Ricard,
  My response to you last question will be done in 3 posts due to the size limit on posts:

Comment: Part 1:
I read the following from the Google Engineer but totally disagree with the assessment:
"To clarify, no change has occurred with Google OAuth that affects proxies. If your requests are indeed correct but you receive 400 Bad Requests from Google's OAuth servers only when going through your proxy, than your proxy is not abiding by the above mentioned W3C standards and the OAuth request arguments are not making it through your proxy to the Google OAuth server."

Comment: Part 2:
"It is recommended to investigate the exact requests coming out of your proxy via logging to ensure they are indeed correct. Google OAuth servers do not care where the request comes from (e.g if it was a proxy) and only checks to make sure the request arguments and body coming in are correct [1]. If they are not correct, it will respond with the 400 HTTP response (which would first return to your proxy, and then in turn be seen by your client)."

Comment: Part 3:
This issue was found on multiple Proxy Servers and by multiple customers.
So, to not get into a discussion with Google on this, we just changed our requests to use Relative Paths instead of Absolute Paths for the Google APIs.

We are continuing to send Absolute Path with a Proxy Server with our Microsoft Dynamics 365 integration which works fine.

And, as mentioned when I opened the Google issue, this was working and then just stopped which was found by multiple customers.